# Running Cypress Script on Browser Stack getting an error spawn npm ENOENT

Tags: cypress, browserstack

I was trying to Integrate my Cypress scripts and execute in Browser Stack.
While executing the script from the Visual code terminal using browserstack-cypress run I am receiving the following error. Appreciate if someone can advise on how to resolve

Issue that shows is Erro: spwan npm ENOENT

[image]

Comment: please post the text, not a picture of text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keeping "cache_dependencies": false in run_settings in browserstack.json may help. Reference: https://www.browserstack.com/docs/automate/cypress/npm-packages#npm-dependency-caching

Comment: Hi Kai, i gave "cache_dependencies": false in run_settings and executed but then  error: Automate testing time has expired. Contact BrowserStack Support at https://www.browserstack.com/contact for extending your Free Trial. We have license and yet we are facing this error.